# How to write category and subcategory with foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a database category table , With 3 fields id,name,cate . And I put it into array

```
$select = $this->db->get_where('cate',array('cate >'=> 0))->result_array();
```

I want to write a foreach that

```
if (cate == 1) : This is the main menu 
else if (cate == main menu id) : this is subcategory
```

Here is what I have tried

```
foreach ($select as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value['id']; 
    $name = $value['name'];
    $cate = $value['cate'];             
}
```

I'm sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

it's my solution:

```
$categoriesHierchy = [];
foreach ($categories as $mainCategory) {
    $childNode = [
        'id' => $mainCategory->getID(),
        'polishName' => $mainCategory->getPolishName(),
        'children' => findChildrenOfCategory($mainCategory)
    ];
    array_push($categoriesHierchy, $childNode);
}

public function findChildrenOfCategory($category)
{
    $children = [];
    if (count($category->getChildren()) > 0) {
        foreach ($category->getChildren() as $child) {
            $childCategories = findChildrenOfCategory($child);
            $childNode = [
                'id' => $child->getID(),
                'polishName' => $child->getPolishName(),
                'children' => $childCategories
            ];
            array_push($children, $childNode);
        }
    }
    return $children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($select as $value) { //selecting each row/element
    $cate = $value['cate']; //grabbing column values
    $name = $value['name'];
    If($cate == 1){ //no need of cate == main cate id
       echo $name." is a main";
    }else{
       echo $name." is a sub";
    }             
}
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25765176)